# extract the text inside html tag via XPath

Tags: xml, linux, xpath, terminal, tags

How can I extract the text inside html tag via XPath?

A sample XML file is:

```
<day d="1" t="Wednesday" dt="Feb 20">
```

so the output will be like this

```
Wednesday
Feb 20
```

i've tried using this

```
xpath -q -e '//day[@d="1"]/@t| //day[@d="1"]/@dt'  ~/day.txt
```

and the output

```
t="Wednesday"
dt="Feb 20"
```

is it worth to use or any other way ? thanks and sorry for my newbie question

### Regards

Regards

Comment: I don't have access to a linux terminal to check this so I've not written a full answer, but what you're asking the XPath evaluator to do is return the attribute, which it is doing and disaplying. I believe if you wrap the expressions in the string function you will get a string representation only (without the `t=`), so if you run the following command it should work `xpath -q -e 'string(//day[@d="1"]/@t)| string(//day[@d="1"]/@dt)'  ~/day.txt`. Let me know if it does and I'll write it up as a full answer!

Comment: Function [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string) probably will do it. But I think the better way is to use [`concat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-concat) for this situation, for example, `//day[@d="1"]/concat(@t, "\n", @dt)`.

Comment: thanks, function string does well to print one of them (@dt or @t), when place it to both side it's return "Both sides of a union must be Node Sets"

Comment: @MikeKaskun yes completely agree with you I prefer that solution to mine! Alfa I suspect my syntax isn't exactly correct, have you tried the solution Mike has given?

Comment: @AlfaAlfafa any update?

Comment: Thanks Dan and Mike, so far i use `concat(//day[@d="1"]/@t , '/' ,//day[@d="1"]/@dt)`